# Creating a CSV file from heterogeneous Python dictionaries

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, dictionary

I have a list of Python dictionaries (retrieved MongoDB documents) that are heterogeneous in structure. This heterogeneity is by no means straightforward, either. All dicts will contain a certain subset of keys. Some dicts will have keys that others do not have. Two dicts may have the same keys, but the structure underneath those keys may differ. The value of one key for two dicts may be a list in each, but the lengths of the list may differ. I need to essentially flatten all of the dicts and write them to a CSV file. Here is a list of two very heavily abridged example dicts:

```
[
  {
    'answers': {
      'age': 25.0,
      'emotion_indices': [34.0951, 16.8922, 19.3003],
      'hearing_impairments': False,
      'music_styles': [
        'rock',
        'pop',
        'classical',
      ],
      'ratings': {
        'activity': [4.0, 3.0, 1.0],
        'positivity': [5.0, 4.0, 3.0],
      },
    },
    'timestamps': {
      'media': [
        datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 29, 11, 18, 26),
        datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 29, 11, 21, 51),
        datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 29, 11, 24, 13)
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    'answers': {
      'age': 16.0,
      'emotion_indices': None,
      'hearing_impairments': False,
      'music_styles': [
        'rock', 
        'pop', 
      ],
      'ratings': {
        'activity': [2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0],
        'like_dislike': [1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0],
        'positivity': [1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0],
      },
    },
    'timestamps': {
      'media': [
        datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 13, 19, 9, 50),
        datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 13, 19, 13, 26),
        datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 13, 19, 16, 2),
        datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 13, 19, 18, 1)],
      'test': datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 13, 19, 8, 36)
    },
  }
]
```

There are solutions for flattening these, but I also see big gotchas. For instance, the first dict has a list for `answers.emotion_indices`, but the second has `None`. A 'typical' flattening scheme would represent the first with flattened keys like `'answers.emotion_indices.0'`, `'answers.emotion_indices.1'`, etc., and the first with simply `'answers.emotion_indices'`. The fact that the dicts that *do* have `emotion_indices` lists may have lists of varying sizes further complicates things. My data nerd friends (for whom I have a deep respect) would much rather see this and similar instances all represented with as many `'answers.emotion_indices.#'` as the longest list amongst all records for this field, and those that have either shorter lists or no lists simply show `NA` or similar.

So, my first question is, **is there a generic, flexible way to flatten all of these dicts?** Or, will the process simply be full of finding all of these inconsistencies and handling them individually?

My second problem has to do with writing all of these flattened dicts to a CSV file. The `csv.DictWriter` class handles *missing* values for keys very flexibly. However, as far as I can tell, it does not handle *adding* keys on the fly that were not originally specified when instantiating the `DictWriter`

So, my second question is, **am I wrong on this, or am I stuck iterating over all of the flattened dicts first to gather keys, making the `DictWriter`, and then iterating over all of the dicts again to write them? Or, is there a better way to do this that I'm not seeing?**

Note that because of the amount of data I'm juggling here, it's very likely that I won't be able to do this in memory--I'll have to retrieve the MongoDB documents, flatten the dicts, persist them to files, iterate over the files to gather keys, and then iterate over the files again after my `DictWriter` has been setup?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I see no other way to handle the flattening than to make a pass to accumulate the possible keys and the list of possible types for each key, then another pass to to actually make the output csv since you are correct that you cannot add keys partway thru a csv structure.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism of flattening depends on what you want to do with the flattened file. If you want to use python for further processing, then pickling might be a good option. Another option could be repr.

Comment: I want to create a CSV file—that's it. I don't really care about what happens with it after I generate the file. `pickle` and `repr` really don't have anything to do with what I'm asking here.